# Google Calendar app URL Scheme in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, google-calendar-api

I want to force open google calendar app instead on native iOS calendar app on iOS from cordova/phonegap application . I reseached on internet but didn't find the url scheme to open google calendar app on iOS.

I have already tried cordova calendar(https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) plugin but it only opens native iOS calendar app and don't have any option to open google calendar instead.

App Availability(https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability) plugin can open app installed on iOS and it requires registered url scheme for the iOS app which i don't know. I try to pass package identifier(com.google.calendar) of google calendar app instead of url scheme but it didn't help. So it only requires url scheme.

Can anyone guide me how to find url scheme of google calendar app on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Download Google Calendar on iTunes from your computer. Rename the `.ipa` to `.zip` and extract it. There's "`Google Calendar.app`" in `Payload/`, left click to "Show Package Contents" and look for `Info.plist`. You'll get the configurations including URL scheme, as in v1.3.1:

- vnd.google.calendar
- com.google.calendar
- comgooglecalendar
- googlecalendar

However, there seems to be no public documentation for this, so use with caution.