# URI scheme for time events

Tags: calendar, protocols, uri-scheme

Is there any [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) or protocol for time events? For example, for location is the [geo URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme), which will open Google Maps or any other map application in mobile devices. I want something similar, but for opening Google Calendar or any other event manager application.

Is there an URI scheme for that? If yes, which one? If no, how could I achieve that?

PS: I want this for a mobile web app, no native code involve.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to find any URI Schemes for time events, I have tried [cap://](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4324) and [webcal://](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal) with no success. But maybe you can use the mimeType 'text/calendar' for this instead.

If what you want is to open the google calendar app, you can use the URI Scheme for google calendar: [comgooglecalendar://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171665/google-calendar-app-url-scheme-in-ios) or the [specific google calendar path](https://gist.github.com/louisbl/8541880).
In case you want the native iOS calendar [you should use calshow://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820762/does-ios-calendar-support-a-url-scheme).

Comment: Wow, tha's the info I was looking for, I'll check it later, thanks for the answer

Comment: @YerkoPalma: no problem. Let me know if that works for you as I'm interested on it too.